# Sending Telegram messages with Telethon: some entity parameters work, others don't?

Tags: python, entity, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I'm using Telethon's [send_message](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telethon.client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message) function to send messages to various chats.

Sometimes, the destination is another user (just a regular one on one chat), sometimes a group, sometimes a supergroup, and sometimes a channel (of which I'm admin).

If I understand correctly, the syntax is supposed to be:

`client.send_message(entity,text)`

But I can't figure out what the `entity` parameter is supposed to be in different cases. What I find especially confusing is specifying an integer id seems to work fine for some groups, but not for others.

For example:

I have a normal 1-to-1 chat with someone who has user_id `11111`, and also with another person who has user_id `22222`.
Furthermore I'm in two groups (supergroups actually) which have channel_id `33333` and `44444`.

I can specify `11111` or `33333` as entity, and the message gets sent correctly (to the first person or the first group respectively). However if I specify `22222` or `44444`, I'm getting an error:

> Cannot find any entity corresponding to "{}"'.format(string)
>   ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "22222"

I am also *receiving* mesasges from all 4 chats using this same Telethon instance, and that's working all fine.

So my question is: **how do I get the correct entity data for send_message()?**

Comment: Try `client.send_message(PeerUser(user_id=11111), 'test-message')`, where `11111` is chat_id you send message to, also add line `from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest reading this section of the document ([entities][1])

for example, I want to send the message to a user with the username: `alix`

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash,
                    )
client.start()
destination_user_username='alix'
entity=client.get_entity(destination_user_username)
client.send_message(entity=entity,message="Hi")
```

or I want to send the message to a channel with username: `test_ali3`

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash
                    )
client.start()

destination_channel_username='test_ali3'
entity=client.get_entity(destination_channel_username)
client.send_message(entity=entity,message="Hi")
```

or I want to send the message to a group with **invite_link**: `https://t.me/joinchat/Bn4WIhMF1T_ZAF-yM6WbHw`

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash
                    )
client.start()
destination_group_invite_link='https://t.me/joinchat/Bn4WIhMF1T_ZAF-yM6WbHw'
entity=client.get_entity(destination_group_invite_link)
client.send_message(entity=entity,message="Hi")
```

I hope to be useful to you.
[1]: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html